# Add unique ID number to end of permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I'm building a membership based website that will use custom post types to store data. I came across a problem which is if two users happen to create a post using the same exact name, WordPress would add -2, to one of the users posts. I'd like to keep permalinks on and have a unique ID added to the end of the permalink so that the URL's appear as example.com/postname-XXX, where XXX is a unique ID.

I thought about using the post ID, but if a user is submitting from a form which is creating the custom post types am I able to insert the post ID before the post or permalink are set and if so how?

If this isn't possible what is another method to add a unique ID to the permalink from the form?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you use the function `wp_insert_post()` from the form to create the post; the function return the ID and you can use it.

```
    if ( defined( 'WP_DEBUG' ) && WP_DEBUG )
        $wp_error = TRUE;
    // insert post
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $new_postarr, $wp_error );
```

Comment: How does this add an ID (a number) to the end of the post name or permalink?

Comment: The permalink have on default a key for this, create the permalink rules in settings and ready.